# SQL Server: How to create a temp table with unkown columns dataype/names?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to make a query on multiple databases. I got the part for building the query for every database but now i need to put the result in something for each query then i can return it.

@requete is a query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RequeteMultiBd]
    @requete varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

    --get server + database name
    select dbo.trim(Serveur)+'.'+ dbo.trim(db) as name, row_number() over (order by db) seq into #tmp from dbo.DataBase;

    declare @name sysname
    declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    declare @seq int
    set @seq = 0

    --getting the next name and seq
    select top 1 @name = name, @seq = seq
            from #tmp where seq > @seq order by seq

    set @sql = replace(@requete, '<bd>', @name);
    --Trying to init the table (that part doesnt work)
    insert into #result exec( @sql );

    --Filling up the table
    WHILE (1=1)
    BEGIN
        select top 1 @name = name, @seq = seq
            from #tmp where seq > @seq order by seq
        if(@@rowcount = 0) break;

        set @sql = replace(@requete, '<bd>', @name);
        insert into #result exec( @sql );

    END
    select * from #result

END
```

From that code i get this error because #result doesn't exit. I need to create it with dynamic column names but how ?

> Invalid object name '#result'

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SELECT .... INTO #Result FROM ...`

This will create the table with the correct columns.

http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_select_into.asp

Comment: What are the "..." ?
i tryed : select * into #result from exec( @sql );
but i get :
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'.

Comment: Requete looks like dynamic SQL. 

You could put the INTO inside the exec(). Like this exec('SELECT * INTO 'Result FROM (' + @requete + ') R

Comment: Actually after playing the #Result declared inside the exec is not visible to the calling sproc... sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to share a temp table between procedure calls, I never did it between databases though...

check out this:

[How to Share Data Between Stored Procedures by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#temptables)

Comment: I cant because this procedure can be called by multiple user at the same time. The data would be wrong in that temp table.

Comment: the temp table is local to the calling scope, each run gets its own table, just like each run gets their own variables.

Comment: if you create a temp table in a procedure, every procedure that is then called from that procedure can select/insert/update/delete within that original temp table, thus sharing the table.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use dynamic sql to run your stored procedure, you can call it like:

```
EXEC @requete '<bd>', @name
```

where @requete is a valid name like server.owner.procedure_name

Comment: I forgot to translate one variable (i write in french) @reqete = query. I replace all <bd> in my query with the database of the current loop.